# Cloudconvert v2 ,Trying to get thumbnail from mp4 file

Tags: cloudconvert

In cloudconvert api v2 , i want  to get thumbnail from mp4 video, in v1 there was option for it,but in v2 cant find solution

Answer (score 0):

There is thumbnail task, which  you can use,I just test, it works.